# Merge two red black trees with the same black height

Tags: balanced-search-trees, red-black-trees

Consider two red-black trees T1 and T2, each with black-height h, with all values in T1 less than all values in T2. How to merge these two trees to obtain a red-black tree in O(h). The root is always considered black in the red-black tree

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.